# Transparency/brightness of inactive/unfocused windows in GNOME Shell

Tags: focus, opacity, gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

Is it possible to make inactive windows (i.e., windows without focus) less opaque, more transparent, less bright or somehow shaded in GNOME Shell? I'd like to have stronger visual feedback on which window is currently active / focused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK it's not possible by default. An easy way to implement it is to write a gnome extension. I already check if one of them is doing something similar for what you are looking for but it doesn't exist right now.

Available extensions can be found there : https://extensions.gnome.org

This one looks closer to your needs: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/650/shade-inactive-windows/

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, shade-inactive-windows doesn't support GNOME 3.20. I filed a bug report. There's also this dead project which might do the trick if it was updated and maintained: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/684/transparent-windows/

Comment: I just tested shade-inactive-windows on gnome 3.18.4 and it works. You just have to change shell-version to 3.20 inside the metadata file inside the extension directory. In shade-inactive-windows extension web page someone tested it successfully on 3.20.

    "shell-version": ["3.20"],

Extension directory is located to ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/

Comment: For 3.38 `git clone https://github.com/elliotwutingfeng/shade-inactive-windows.git ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/shade-inactive-windows@hepaajan.iki.fi`. (See issue 13 of the original extension: https://github.com/hepaajan/shade-inactive-windows/issues/13